# How to create all of the vectors that are some sample vector missing one element?

Tags: c++, vector

I have some vector of elements passed to a function and I want to create all of the vectors that are that original vector, but with one element missing.

What is the simplest way to do this in C++?

My current approach is something of the following, but not quite worked out yet.

```
void list_one_removed(std::vector<Fruit> fruit)
{
    for (unsigned i = fruit.size(); i > 0; i--)
    {
        // copy 'fruit'
        // remove index i
        // add this vector to some vector of vectors.
    }
}
```

Comment: too vague, will get closed unless you add more detail (input/output and possibly your current code).

Comment: It seems the answer is pretty simple when you show us some code!

Comment: The *simplest* would be to iterate over the length of the vector: make a copy and delete the kth element from it. Is that good enough?

Comment: Thanks, I'll update with code now.

Comment: @Beta yeah, that's generally what I was doing, but it seems like it wouldn't be the best way.  I've updated the question with my initial hypothesized approach

Comment: Anyone else going to point out that loop has an invalid index from the start and will immediately read out of bounds of the array?

Comment: @SionSheevok I would be referencing i - 1 :)

Comment: The first statement would run, initializing `i` to `fruits.size()`. Then, the second statement would evaluate as the looping condition, `i > 0`. Then, if true, the body of the `for` loop would execute. If `fruits` has 5 elements, `i` would equal `5`, `i > 0` would evaluate true, and, if you access the `i`th element of `fruits`, you would be accessing `fruits[5]`, which would be beyond the bounds of the vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, just use an iterator to identify the currently removed position and create a vector from everything up to this iterator and everything after this iterator:

```
std::vector<decltype(vec)> result;
for (auto it(vec.begin()), end(vec.end()); it != end; ) {
    result.push_back(decltype(vec)(vec.begin(), it));
    result.back().insert(result.back().end(), ++it, vec.end());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm having trouble understanding a bit of the syntax.  What in this skips the current location of the iterator?  And is 'result' a vector of vector of Fruit objects?  The decltype notation is new to me.  Thanks :)

Comment: First the `decltype(expr)` is just determining the type of the expression `expr`. It is a new feature in C++2011. So, yes, result is a vector of vectors. Other than this, the magic is in the sequences of iterators taken to constructor the iterator at the end of `result`: it is constructed from the sequence `[begin, it)` and then the sequence `[++it, end)`. The magic skipping the "current" element is in the `++it` which skips over it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `<algorithm>` and C++11:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

// personally, I would pass "in" as a couple of iterators
template<typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> list_one_removed(const std::vector<T>& in)

{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> result;
    for (auto itor = in.begin(); itor != in.end(); ++itor) {
        std::vector<T> buffer;
        std::copy_if(in.begin(),
                     in.end(),
                     std::back_inserter(buffer),
                     [&itor](const T& t){ return &t != &(*itor); });
        result.emplace_back(std::move(buffer));
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you have the new "for each" loop, you can do:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> list_one_removed(const std::vector<T>& in)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> result;
    for (const auto& foo : in) {
        std::vector<T> buffer;
        std::copy_if(in.begin(),
                     in.end(),
                     std::back_inserter(buffer),
                     [&foo](const T& t){ return &t != &foo; });
        result.emplace_back(std::move(buffer));
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you're using C++03:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template<typename T> struct identity {
    const T& id_;
    identity(const T& id) : id_(id) { }

    bool operator()(const T& other) const
    {
        return &id_ == &other;
    }
};

template<typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T> > list_one_removed(const std::vector<T>& in)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T> > result;
    for (typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator itor = in.begin();
         itor != in.end();
         ++itor) {
        std::vector<T> buffer;
        std::remove_copy_if(in.begin(),
                            in.end(),
                            std::back_inserter(buffer),
                            identity<T>(*itor));
        result.push_back(buffer);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Dietmar's answer should be more efficient, and much more for your C++03 variant with its unneccessary vector copy at the end. But also the C++11 variants with their many comparisons and push_back-caused reallocations aren't that optimal.

Comment: @Christian:  I originally had calls to `std::vector::reserve` to avoid needless reallocations.  However, I removed them because (1) they cluttered the example code, and (2) I have a hunch we're talking about vectors with less than 10 elements.  As for the C++03 version:  you have heard of return value optimization, named return value optimization and copy elision, right?

Comment: Well yes, I have. But I don't have that much believe into the compiler to just leave out such a simple optimization (push and use back instead of temporary and push). I doubt that `push_back` will really elide the internal copy of `buffer`, given that it takes it as a const reference and doesn't itself know that `buffer` is destroyed right after the call, that's what the new move semantics are for.

Comment: @Christian, I think we're now talking about different things w/r/t C++03. RVO, copy elision, etc. only help on the `return result;` line. You are correct that the C++03 `push_back` calls do make an unnecessary temporary; which is why the C++11 version uses `emplace_back`. You are correct that I could `push_back` an empty vector and manipulate it. I'll keep it in mind, although I'll leave it out of the sample code for the same reason I removed the `reserve` calls: it affects clarity (I added the C++03 code because my original statement that "C++03 would be similar" was overly-optimistic).